# Mobile Browser Disabling CSS

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-browser

What would be causing a mobile browser to disable all CSS?

Screenshot:
[Website Screenshot](http://www.clwebsites.com/screenshot/Screenshot_2013-12-05-21-11-46.png)

Comment: A million and one things... you need specifics. What phone, os version, the basic code for the CSS, etc.

Comment: Have you put the phone into debug mode and looked at the console?
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Answer (score 0):

when you access the website on your mobile is already like this?

If yes maybe you linked the css file wrong for  the mobile, see if you put wrong.
Sometimes one wrong line of code  mess all up ^^.